# Copy scheduling information form local system to remote system  SSRS

Tags: ssrs

I    am scheduling some reports locally in my system.
How can I copy this schedule information to remote system to avoid re-doing of scheduling at remote system?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ["Reporting Services Scripter"](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) which uses the web service API of SSRS to migrate stuff. I'm not sure how up to date it is, last updated 2009 However, I've foundthis useful in previous jobs.

Copying at the database level won't be enough: scheduled tasks are SQL Server Agent jobs that also need migrated. For more, see "[How to: Migrate a Reporting Services Installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143724.aspx)"